# Which is better to use in professionally (web.xml(Deployment descriptor) or @WebServlet annotation?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Earlier servlet version (less than 3.0), we used web.xml file as Deployment descriptor:
**web.xml**

```
<web-app>  
 <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>WebServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>  
  </servlet>   

  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>WebServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>   

  <welcome-file-list>  
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>
```

Now with the help of tomcat 7.0 and servlet v3.0, we use @WebServlet annotation.
E.g:

```
@WebServlet(
    name = "AnnotatedServlet",
    description = "A sample annotated servlet",
    urlPatterns = {"/Login"}
)
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    // servlet code here...
}
```

Now my question is **which is better to use professionally?**
Need your honest suggestion. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your need:

- If you prefer to keep all the configuration stuff in one place, go for `web.xml`;
- Otherwise, if you think (as I do), that the XML configuration files become too heavy when we deal with a big number of declarations and configuration items, go for annotations.

I personally prefer annotations, as it belongs the my Java code and I find myself on it and dealing with big XML configuration files (maybe it's not your case here) is boring and takes a lot of time, for me, to get what I am looking for (this is my personal opinion).

On the other hand, the latter doesn't matter, because, when application works fine, no one will ask you what have you chosen for your servlet declaration.

Answer (score 2):

This question is rather subjective. Some people like to separate behavior from configuration and so prefer to use XML configuration. Personally, I prefer using annotations since I can see the configuration *right there* when I read the code. Pick a style you prefer, and stick to it. While it is possible to mix configuration styles, I recommend staying consistent and using one style.

Answer (score 0):

Let's put it in this way: If an annotation provides functionality and acts as a comment in and of itself, and doesn't tie the code down to some specific process in order to function normally without this annotation, then go for annotations. For example, a transactional method marked as being transactional does not kill its operating logic, and serves as a good code-level comment as well. Otherwise, this information is probably best expressed as XML, because although it will eventually affect how the code operates, it won't change the main functionality of the code, and hence doesn't belong in the source files.

So here I recommend you xml configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way is to **stick with one style**, so new programmers don't get confused about one way or the other.

If your container supports annotation, stick with it, but make it a rule (you can make a convention for the whole company).

Another thing that you should consider is that with **XML** configuration files, all your configuration is inside one file, making it easier to understand the system without navigating through all the files.