# How exactly does Java-based configuration work in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration

I have no trouble in understanding how XML-based configuration works with Spring MVC. There is a standard file ("web.xml") in a standard directory ("WEB-INF/").
How does a server knows that this class is responsible for front-servlet initialization though?

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RootApplicationContextConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebApplicationContextConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

Looking at this file, I can easily understand that a server will load the servlet on startup with the highest priority.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Servlet specification 3.0 you can use [web.xml or annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475426/which-is-better-to-use-in-professionally-web-xmldeployment-descriptor-or-web) to configure servlets, and with the annotation based configuration additional mechanisms were included to make `web.xml` unnecessary. I'm not sure if there are cases where `web.xml` is still useful, I can't remember touching one in years.

[SpringServletContainerInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html) class implements the [javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) which is the starting point for the servlet container (e.g. Tomcat) to set things up.

Comment: There is no `@WebServlet` involved. There is a special [`SpringServletContainerInitializer.html`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html). Which is a `ServletContainerInitialize` as defined by Servlet 3.0 spec. This in turn will lookup `WebApplicationInitializer` instances on the classpath and as the `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` is a `WebApplicationInitializer` classes extending this will be found and called.

Comment: @M.Deinum ah thank you, that does make more sense than going through all classes.